# Tell if two polygons are colliding

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, vertex-arrays, error-management

I want to make a function like `areColliding` which takes two polygons as args.
I also want to cover cases like

[image: case 1]

and the dreaded

[image: case 2]

because I am trying to create a framework and I think that it should be as accurate as possible.

```js
var polygon1 = [
  [1, 1],
  [2, 5],
  [5, 3],
];
var polygon2 = [
  [1, 1],
  [2, 5],
  [3, 5],
  [7, 4],
  [1, 3],
  [2, 1],
  [1, 0],
];
areColliding(polygon1, polygon2) //=> true
areColliding([[1, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]) //=> Error
areColliding({}, [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]) //=> Error
areColliding([[1,1],[2,2],[3,0]], [[7,7],[5,7],[6,8]]) //=> false
```

Comment: So, presumably you did a search for standard algorithms for this and found options like Separating Axis Theorem, GJK, etc? What have you tried based on your research thus far?